# Ts failing to type as undefined when undefined is in a union

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

First sorry if this has been asked before, i couldn't find it. My issue is the following:

I have an interface "BaseCondition" with a property called "isGeneralized", that I typed like this.

```
isGeneralized: boolean | undefined
```

The problem is that that it ends up being recognized as this

```
(property) BaseCondition.isGeneralized: boolean
```

I tried with other types like "string | undefined", but it still types it only as "string" or whatever type you put.

This happens only in the api, on the web app is working fine. So I copy pasted the tsconfig from the webapp to the api, but still the issue persists.

This is the tsconfig.json:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "noUnusedLocals": true /* Report errors on unused locals. */,
    "noUnusedParameters": true /* Report errors on unused parameters. */,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, // no errors on commonjs default import
    "allowJs": true, // include js files
    "checkJs": true, // typecheck js files
    "declaration": false, // don't emit declarations
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "importHelpers": true, // importing helper functions from tslib
    "noEmitHelpers": true, // disable emitting inline helper functions
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
},
"include": ["src/**/*", "src/**/*.json"],
"exclude": ["node_modules", "coverage", "**/*.test.ts"]
```

}

How can I make the ts compiler properly recognize the undefined type put in the union?

Comment: This has probably to do with the fact these types have falsy values by default. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Comment: `isGeneralized` will always have a  boolean value . If the value is undefined it will be converted to false

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72826074/edit) and add a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? So other users can test it and find an answer for you. I've stumbled upon this once and the problem was a wrong declaration file (`*.d.ts`).

Comment: @lepsch thanks! the issue is that I cant replicate on a ts code sandbox, it works fine there :(

Comment: @ManosKounelakis but why though? Even if i put "string" | undefined it will be typed as "string" only

Comment: Can you share a repository for others to test?

Answer (score 0):

With the tsconfig and the example you shared, typescript (v4.7.3) *will* recognize `isGeneralized` as `boolean | undefined`.

Typescript implemented strict null checks in v2.0 (see [release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#--strictnullchecks)). If the version in use is below v2.0, the rule will be ignored.

The editor you are using may not resolve the tsconfig the way it is defined in the build scripts. There is also a possibility that the editor has just resolved the tsconfig incorrectly.

Verify the the typescript version to be or above v2.0, make sure the tsconfig is resolved correctly, and compile the project with tsc (the editor might be wrong).